# .Net time string conversion in Coldfusion

Tags: .net, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have a six digit time string coming from .NET I would like to convert to a timestamp in ColdFusion. What would be the correct way to convert this?

```
string= 20190126195631
```

The date is simple:

```
thisDate = '#mid(string,5,2)#/#mid(string,7,2)#/#mid(string,1,4)#'
```

To get the time I've tried:

```
timestamp = timeFormat(parseDateTime(mid(string,9,6)),'HH:mm')
```

What do I do with the `195631` to show the timestamp?

Comment: Many people use the JAVA method `formatter.parse()` https://www.petefreitag.com/item/569.cfm

Comment: I wrote UDFs to convert back and forth. Use DateUnhash to convert the string to a date/time value. https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/8961085

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Too long for comments...)

> time = '#mid(string,9,2)**-8#**

Don't just subtract 8 from the hour because it'll return an invalid values like "-1" AM or "-8" AM, when the UTC value is between midnight and 7AM.

Also, if you're converting the value to local time, don't forget about daylight savings time changes. An offset of 8 hours may change to 7 hours, depending on the time of year and zone. Instead of using a hard coded number, take a look at the [DateConvert](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateConvert.html) function to convert UTC to local time and using [ParseDateTime](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html) with a mask, instead of multiple string functions.

Keep in mind there are pros, cons .. and sadly potential bugs/gotchas .. with all of the suggested approaches, depending on your version of CF. So be sure to test with variety of date values and time zones.

**ColdFusion 2016+ syntax** (Note, uses "nn" for minutes. [Runnable Example](https://trycf.com/gist/c1495eabc06f407ed342333cd44adec7/acf2016?theme=monokai))

```
str = "20190126175631";
utcDate = parseDateTime(str, "yyyyMMddHHnnss");
localDate = DateConvert("utc2Local", utcDate);

writeOutput("utcDate ="& utcDate &" localDate = "& localDate);
```

**ColdFusion 10/11 syntax** (Note, uses "mm" for minutes. [Runnable Example](https://trycf.com/gist/9cb63c47566ee8ef1d3efe696426ca0b/acf?theme=monokai))

```
str = "20190126175631";
utcDate = parseDateTime(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss");
localDate = DateConvert("utc2Local", utcDate);

writeOutput("utcDate ="& utcDate &" localDate = "& localDate);
```

Comment: Yes I had a -8 error at about 4 P.M. PST because 0-8 was not a valid time.  The dateConvert is the correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like pop conversion uses mm for minutes rather than nn Message: yyyyMMddHHnnss is not a valid date format. yyyyMMddHHmmss https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: **Updated with example** @StephenSharpe - Yeah, `nn` works in CF2016+, while CF10/11 uses `mm` (which is what I was implying by gotchas/depending on version). Are you using CF10/11? If so, might want to update the question tags. I (wrongly) assumed you were using 2016+

Comment: @CharlesRobertson - Simpler, but ...since Adobe broke backward compatability :-/ ... thinking about it, String functions (or Java) is more resilient for the parsing aspect  when you upgrade. I'd keep DateConvert for the translation to local time though.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! Your comments helped me realize the time is simply: HHMMSS 19 = 7 p.m., 56 mins and 31 secs.

What threw me off was the GMT (-8 hours for me) shift. 
So the answer is:

```
time = '#mid(string,9,2)-8#:#mid(string,11,2)#'
```

Comment: The above will fail under some conditions.  See [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383387/8895292)

Comment: Edit - wrong link. Should be https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384804/8895292

Answer (score 2):

I might be going mad here, but it looks like the string could be split like this:

```
2019-01-26 19:56:31
```

So, using Coldfusion:

```
<cfset datetimestring = "20190126195631">

<cfset year = Mid(datetimestring,1,4)>
<cfset month = Val(Mid(datetimestring,5,2))>
<cfset day = Val(Mid(datetimestring,7,2))>
<cfset hour = Val(Mid(datetimestring,9,2))>
<cfset minute = Val(Mid(datetimestring,11,2))>
<cfset second = Val(Mid(datetimestring,13,2))>


<cfset dateTime = CreateDateTime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)>

<cfset dateTimeOffset = DateAdd("h", -8, dateTime)>

<cfoutput>
#dateTimeOffset#
</cfoutput>
```

As, I said this string could just be an epoch timestamp, but it does look like a 'date time' pattern?